# How to sum the two largests elements in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sub-array

I have a list like this:

```
[1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5...]
```

Is there an effective way to find the sum of the 2 largest elements here without:

```
for i in range():
    for j in range():
```

I've found this:
"Maximum subarray problem"

But I've not completely understand what it does.

Comment: so in this case the result would be `9` + `7` ?

Comment: You can sort array so that biggest numbers are at the start and then sum 2 first elements

Comment: Yes, but In my case I have a random list. I get it as inputs and I try to avoid making for in for to check every element

Comment: @TrueBad0ur you should clarify something very important. What is the desired output when the max happens more than once? For example if your list is `[1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 9]`, is your desired answer `9+9` or `9+7`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sum(sorted([9,8,1,3,4,5,7,0])[-2:])
```

1. sorted all elements
2. get two last elements
3. sum it

Comment: or `sum(sorted([9,8,1,3,4,5,7,0], reverse=True)[0:2])`

Comment: There should be a `O(N)` solution though

Comment: Or we could use `sum(heapq.nlargest(2, your_list))`

Comment: This is an n log n solution to a linear problem; should not be accepted. Others have already given linear time solutions: read the array once, keep track of the two largest elts, and add them at the end.

Comment: @Dave That depends... In terms of pure performance you're right, this is sub-optimal. But, you know, if you don't have millions of numbers, the difference between this solution and a linear one in terms of performance is going to be micro-seconds. The *big* difference however is that this code is way more readable.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a linear time solution:

```
#initialize these to huge negative numbers
largest = -1e10
second_largest = -1e11
l = [9,8,1,3,4,5,7,0]
for item in l:
    if item > largest:
        second_largest = largest
        largest = item
    elif item > second_largest:
        second_largest = item

print(largest+second_largest)
# 17
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is linear solution:

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]
max1 = -1;
max2 = -1;
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] > max1:
        max2 = max1
        max1 = x[i]
    elif x[i] > max2:
        max2 = x[i]

print(max1+max2)
```

If your array consists only of positive integers, otherwise consider changing max1, max2 to lowest possible value

Answer (score 3):

Another O(n) solution, but a bit more pythonic, giving up a bit of performance (iterating 4 times over the list)

```
l = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]

# find largest
largest = max(l)
# remove from list
l.remove(largest)
# second largest
largest2 = max(l)
# remove from list
l.remove(largest2)
print(largest+largest2)
>> 16
```

And to make it a bit more compact, the exact same process in one line:

```
l = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]
l.pop(l.index(max(l))) + l.pop(l.index(max(l)))
print(largest+largest2)
>> 16
```

Comment: You don't need `l.remove(largest2)`, but this works.

Comment: I love this solution. Simple and efficient. If you are not allowed to use the built-in max() and remove(), you can code them, but I love the simplicity of the idea.

Comment: This solution might work or not, depending on your definition of "largest". What happens if the largest numbers are duplicate? Should you remove all instances of it, which is another \$O(n)\$ operation, or give `largest * 2` as a result?

Comment: Not really, remove will remove the first match of the largest value. next step will find the same max (different index) and will remove it. so quick answer is it will have the same bahaviour just as the rest of the solutions (eg sort, get [:2]). It will result largest * 2

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a library, you can use `heapq`'s [`nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq
x = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]
```

Then

```
sum(heapq.nlargest(2, x))
```

will return

```
16
```

Also [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) is an option (but use it only if you import it anyway as it is a rather heavy dependency):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(x).nlargest(2).sum()
```

also returns `16`

In case you have **duplicated maxima**, you can use `sets`:

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5, 9]
```

Then

```
sum(heapq.nlargest(2, x))
```

will return

```
18
```

as `9 + 9 = 18` and

```
sum(heapq.nlargest(2, set(x)))
```

will return

```
16
```

as it then calculates `9 + 7 = 16`.

Answer (score 1):

## With unique numbers

This is the simplest way

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]
m1 = max(a)
a.pop(a.index(m1))
m2 = max(a)
print(m1 + m2)
```

output: 16

If you have more equal number, but you want get rid of them - so that you can add the two biggest DIFFERENT numbers - you can do so:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5]
a = set(a)
m1 = max(a)
a = list(a)
a.pop(a.index(m1))
m2 = max(a)
print(m1 + m2)
```

The output: 16

If you instead want to add the biggest number in a list, even if they are the same (i.e. 9 and 9), use the first code example and it will work for you.